# can you add html colored text to a string including sharedpreferences?

Tags: java, android, html, string, sharedpreferences

My text looses its color(turns to default black), as soon as I add the sharedpreferences string. why?.

```
leveltextfabr1.setText((Html.fromHtml("<font color=#cc0029>colorized text </font>  ")) + (prefs.getString("leveltextfab1", "1")));
```

And I can also set no html color for

```
dialog.setMessage(..my (sadly not) color text..);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `+` operator will convert your `Spanned` (from `Html.fromHtml()`) into a `String`, losing the formatting. [Use `TextUtils.concat()` instead](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html#concat%28java.lang.CharSequence...%29), to retain the formatting.

Answer (score 2):

```
leveltextfabr1.setText(Html.fromHtml("<font color=#cc0029>colorized text </font>  " + prefs.getString("leveltextfab1", "1")));
```

concatenate string within `fromHtml`

Comment: `leveltextfab1` should be html-escaped.

Comment: @DávidHorváth Then you should use `TextUtils#concat` as mentioned by CommonsWare